Can we customize how parameters and return types are imported from Objective-C into Swift?
I have an Objective-C class that is a proxy to an NSDictionary.
@interface DictionaryProxy : NSProxy
-(id)objectForKey:(id)key;
-(void)setObject:(id)obj forKey:(id<NSCopying>)key;
@end

I have not genericized the class because I do not want the type parameters class-constrained in Swift.
Swift imports the class as follows:
class DictionaryProxy : NSProxy {
     func object(forKey key: any NSCopying) -> Any
     func setObject(_ obj: Any, forKey key: any NSCopying)
}

Is there a way for me to customize how the return type for objectForKey: and the key parameter in setObject:forKey: are imported in Swift? After Swift changed to import id as Any, can I selectively import an id type as an AnyHashable or AnyObject?

IMO it's much better to write a new dict proxy in swift and for swift using generics, and then if needs be, make an extension that conforms to DictionaryProxy for backward compatibility.  When you fully migrate from ObjC, you ditch that old wrapper, and keep the new one.
